# Python: convert Dictionary of lists to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I want to convert dictionary of lists to list of tuple
Here is an example: entry data

```
d = {
u'x_axis': [1,2,3,7,8,9],
u'y_axis': [5,6,5,6,5,6],
u'z_axis': [1,2,1,2,1,2],
}
```

What I want to have is:

```
l = [
(1,5,1),
(2,6,2),
(3,5,1),
(7,6,2),
(8,5,1),
(9,6,2),
]
```

The lists in dictionary are same length.

So as you can see, x_axis is in 1st possition in every tuple etc.

A bit like rotation it by -90 degrees

Edit.1
 
I want to have the same order of elements in tuples as order of keys and number of keys is not defined by default. So I could have write keys to some var like:
keys = d.keys()
if I do:
l = here what I want with vars in tuples in order of keys-list

Comment: This is a little "do my homework for me". You should let us know what you have tried.

Comment: I've downvoted this question, as it seems like a homework question, to which you have not provided any information about your own attempts to solve. Stack Overflow is not a place to get your homework done. The question can be improved by adding information about what you have tried. If you didn't try anything before posting; do so next time!

Answer (score 4):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> d = {
...     u'x_axis': [1,2,3,7,8,9],
...     u'y_axis': [5,6,5,6,5,6],
...     u'z_axis': [1,2,1,2,1,2],
... }
>>> list(zip(d['x_axis'], d['y_axis'], d['z_axis']))
[(1, 5, 1), (2, 6, 2), (3, 5, 1), (7, 6, 2), (8, 5, 1), (9, 6, 2)]
```

`list(..)` is not needed in Python 2.x. (In Python 2.x, `zip` returns a list, in Python 3.x, `zip` returns an iterator)

**UPDATE**

Using pre-defined keys:

```
>>> keys = 'x_axis', 'y_axis', 'z_axis'  # OR keys = sorted(d)
>>> list(zip(*(d[key] for key in keys)))
[(1, 5, 1), (2, 6, 2), (3, 5, 1), (7, 6, 2), (8, 5, 1), (9, 6, 2)]
```

NOTE: `keys = d.keys()` will not work because Python dictionary does not guarantee key order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function :

```
>>> zip(*d.values())
[(5, 1, 1), (6, 2, 2), (5, 3, 1), (6, 7, 2), (5, 8, 1), (6, 9, 2)]
```

If you care about the order you should pass the values by a custom order to `zip` function.for example :

```
zip(d['x_axis'], d['y_axis'], d['z_axis'])
```

Or use an `collections.OrderedDict` if you want to use `values()` and unpacking :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict([(u'x_axis', [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]),(u'y_axis', [5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6]), (u'z_axis', [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])])
>>> 
>>> zip(*d.values())
[(1, 5, 1), (2, 6, 2), (3, 5, 1), (7, 6, 2), (8, 5, 1), (9, 6, 2)]
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the `x,y,z` ordering, which may be important, even if not explicitly stated by the op.

Comment: how to do it if I do not know axises names and number. I can remember axises names in array by d.key() and create array like yours by iterating over d, but how to do it more elegant

Comment: @MichałPiotrStankiewicz If you don't know the key names the best way is using an order dict to store your items instead of a simple dictionary!